# Log into asp.net web application with python

Tags: python, asp.net, authentication, python-requests

I'm trying to log in into one web application with python but very attempt ends with 500 error and the html body shows the error: [HttpAntiForgeryException]. I tried to apply a few solutions from the other questions here but nothing helped. So now, I'm sucked at first request which response Is giving me 500.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

url = "http://localhost:52053/Account/Login"

username = "test@test.sk"
user_password = "pass"

session = requests.Session()
response = session.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, features="html.parser")
#print(soup)
states = ["__RequestVerificationToken", "Email", "RememberMe"]
login_data = {"username": username, "password": user_password, "Login": "submit"}
headers = {"Host": "localhost:52053",
           "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
           "Connection": "close",
           "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0)",
           "Cookie": str(session.cookies.get_dict())}

for state in states:  # search for existing aspnet states and get its values
    result = soup.find('input', {'name': state})
    if not (result is None):  # when existent (some may not be needed!)
        if state == "Email":
            login_data.update({state: login_data["username"]})
        else:
            login_data.update({state: result['value']})


post_request = session.post(url, headers=headers, data=login_data)
```

Successful login attempt looks like this.

```
POST /Account/Login HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:52053
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: sk,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 193
Origin: http://localhost:52053
Connection: close
Referer: http://localhost:52053/Account/Login
Cookie: __RequestVerificationToken=j9yFGpTFSlH5_aQt0k-Gvz10I16TVXbDk31NKPm1HkcWsksUfKXkjL567yFplCS_VovTR7lVuEgNjwgp-EO3RjNj4gQOvNUXnPkjymZx_jA1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

__RequestVerificationToken=LjHuOdKSCr1A7KRDNie4GUnCZ3qRwUCdHyLlPYT40DsEB-GNUvEKxe5nvZWf5gZ4ZflwI43xGWPyYu8GI15wroEg9WRRVtSzZ9-KY9Mu_JA1&Email=test%40test.sk&Password=pass&RememberMe=false
```

Following response is:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Location: /
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Set-Cookie: .AspNet.ExternalCookie=; path=/; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT
Set-Cookie: .AspNet.ApplicationCookie=KCLm03FHj8v_6rIpTzBTm7EzEtzpKmIz1Z9_z29wycUSqUVyKbGEmptXUwG41MqNOMR7Vbeq2u576ijazupNLffLP-Ua0n60aLmnVSDsLsdTqYT7jjqyGPw1Ppp8AnIDs3sdefmksazX2UvKTxzxRBufFCoxtCJx51mWtBv7v0JzUeC1hnfu1AIJ7GH_8T59KD3iv0hRSHDqlWHlkWzyN1Xt0m5ixC14e4eC2YxEm3_acy96atB2Jv5u0HREPzssLmywuzj6sLa9cHCllTG2gMVWvHA3IDhCWu7Ojf8BO02Eml3pPM5QTJ-sq540fcj9QyELayUOwBZWffSgsJeq8mlt3FupQcJ-JTJxDzAsDc4Cmk-BcvYSfpAJq4SdR-Y4mTN_6vu-wwAOLZPSgh-5K7guWmZ3VfRitZHXd_rvTEmMiVrgHFTEQAkUYu4zTSupxRplTtKb1VSDs0Nc1uEos2z0_aw-nBbRBrTPpvmqGok
```

Auth flow continues with this request. I'm not trying to sent this request yet (I put it here just for better imagination):

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:52053
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: sk,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://localhost:52053/Account/Login
Connection: close
Cookie: __RequestVerificationToken=j9yFGpTFSlH5_aQt0k-Gvz10I16TVXbDk31NKPm1HkcWsksUfKXkjL567yFplCS_VovTR7lVuEgNjwgp-EO3RjNj4gQOvNUXnPkjymZx_jA1;
.AspNet.ApplicationCookie=gvv113IJhtdaOhdc0Rz2N--5Ob18W6gS64J3wtOJggRTqE70h-8HyBGQAmLvSM2qCV2e-dXR2Uto-BktD6NmNz6dJtxckIYasPOfqodDNZX33YJxNEDg7a64LPi1bNnmrnvQcOHAceQNqZDykXrhFm55dqoo1oZnJHfZQnltwqAdg7DGO31PZpzu-GAZh2_gzuxd_saJdS09ZZQrc9h7WiU2ONqeya87pSAN7ZyHQ_XvsU5cUwDGq7FWLpzlIeeZWkay6iWVmCSwNEofpdVsb880P3XZnFKEj2SW2PfazdNLfgy86YNjkoD6_3Vb1BLirRoSP0XIQMcs2F_CzgXkxD5GvDray8TPYqcQJ4L2fikReUJHadx9fFnslF2BFcnKYC8D-Xusrda_5r-CQoQ4SzAe2Cqn0h1NYHxS1wsxt35neC5RuQ3geadAEEghjrSSVhSl8jCfACtQtcBeNL2x_m6I9L3XJCjMpzJjtP6up3E
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

Next response is just kind of 200 - you are in.

So my problem is that the response from the first request is failing. Is someone able to see some mistake or did I forgot something?

Failed response from the first request call:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcUENBZG1pbmlzdHJhdG9yXERlc2t0b3BccGVuIHRlc3RpbmdcU2VjdXJpdHlXb3Jrc2hvcC1EVldBLW1hc3RlclxkdndhLXRyYWluaW5nXGR2d2EtdHJhaW5pbmdcQWNjb3VudFxMb2dpbg==?=
```

If I try to pint request headers and login_data, result is:

print(post_request.request.headers)

```
{'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0)', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'close', 'Host': 'localhost:52053', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Cookie': "{'__RequestVerificationToken': 'yg-7mFRyZiONwsZ2dIVkIIW5tB7gSL_sazgphg-VuW2OpNNRRkxmLH-9SZJXiN9whUC_BYTo8RgsiDrVjcYtLEf9anW56rVwZ2RQPzxHA481'}", 'Content-Length': '249'}
```

print(login_data)

```
{'username': 'test@test.sk', 'password': 'pass', 'Login': 'submit', '__RequestVerificationToken': '14OuwaRqldlGKi93C91zf6QD_ouOorHBDe63s4KgfP3gbt85V0QMy2X5OMwWAo1TUrD8zJ-zoZbXLPpgDI_wrxVZv3ceYNos_e5_elFhVt01', 'Email': 'test@test.sk', 'RememberMe': 'true', 'Password': 'pass'}
```

Comment: The problem could be you are not passing the `__RequestVerificationToken` either in body or cookies or they are mismatch.

Comment: I understand that. __RequestVerificationToken should be there (at least, when I print headers, it is there). I'm just thinking if they are mismatching somehow or request is build badly but I cant figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just find the solution out.

Requests could handle all headers by itself (and my headers was, for some reason, causing errors), it was redirecting my request to 200 response so I didn't instantly saw, that it is actually working and catching 302 response.

I found out by printing:

```
print(post_request.history)
```

Which gave me <[302]>

Now, when I know, there is a redirection, I just have to `allow_redirects=False` and now I'm able to catch my **set-cookie header**

Full code, witch is getting an expected responses is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://localhost:52053/Account/Login"
username = "test@test.sk"
user_password = "pass"

session = requests.Session()
response = session.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, features="html.parser")
#print(soup)
states = ["__RequestVerificationToken", "Email", "RememberMe"]
login_data = {"username": username, "password": user_password, "Login": "submit"}

for state in states:  # search for existing aspnet states and get its values
    result = soup.find('input', {'name': state})
    if not (result is None):  # when existent (some may not be needed!)
        if state == "Email":
            login_data.update({state: login_data["username"]})
        else:
            login_data.update({state: result['value']})


post_request = session.post(url,  data=login_data, allow_redirects=False)

print(login_data)

#the code below is testing, if the HttpAntiForgeryException is in code

if "HttpAntiForgeryException" not in post_request.text:
    print(post_request.headers)
else:
    print("antiforgery")
```